# Выход за пределы массива, не знаю, почему

Tags: java

Решил попробовать метод пузырьковой сортировки, но, не знаю почему, где `if(mass[i+1] < mass[i])` у меня прога выходит за пределы массива, хотя до этого момента я создал этот массив и присвоил ему различные значения путем `Scanner`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at MassiveList.insert(MassiveList.java:26)
```

Смеяться над моей поистине глупой ошибкой или нет - дело ваше, но за помощь буду очень сильно благодарен.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MassiveList {
    static long mass[];                                 // Massive
    private static int nElems;                          // Massive elements amount
    private static long tmp;
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Listener

    public MassiveList(int a) {                         // Massive length
        mass = new long[a];
        nElems = 0;
        System.out.println("Your massive has " + mass.length + " potential elems");
    }

    public static void insert() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            mass[i] = sc.nextLong();                    // Insert itself
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            if (mass[i + 1] < mass[i]) {
                tmp = mass[i];
                mass[i] = mass[i + 1];
                mass[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: последний цикл `for(int i = 0; i<mass.length; i++)` переделайте на `for(int i = 0; i<mass.length-1; i++)`, так как сйечас у вас падает на `mass[i+1]` когда `i` достигает значения `mass.length-1`

Comment: Только ещё несколько моментов - зачем нужна переменная nElems и такая сортировка за один проход работать не будет, и ещё сканнер нужно закрывать